# Stay in a loop until the right input

Tags: java, loops

Im trying to build a simple guessing game where you choose the range of numbers. I want to stay in my loop until the user guesses the right number. The while loop allows no next input after the first wrong guess. How do I stay inside of a loop until a variable matches?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    test random = new test();
    
    System.out.print("Please input a minumum amount: ");
    int min = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please input a maximum amount: ");
    int max = reader.nextInt();
    
    int answer = random.getRandom(min, max);
    
    System.out.print("Please guess a number between you " + min + "-" + max + ": ");
    int input = reader.nextInt(); 
    
    while(input != answer) {
            System.out.println("Guess again");
    }
    
    if(input == answer) {
        System.out.println("You got it right!");
    }
    
    
}
}
```

Comment: Your statements contradicted each other. ***...to stay in my loop until the user guesses the right number***   and ***while loop allows no next input after the first wrong guess***.   How these two even possible?

Comment: look into Java [`do-while` loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(true){
if(input==answer) break;
else continue;
}
```

Comment: I ended up getting it to work with a do while loop, but this is very short and sweet. Not sure I understand what the "true" in the while loop is comparing to? Will it only break if the input==answer boolean comes true?

Comment: `while(true)` means it runs while its true that means it will be running forever. If the input is answer, the `break` statement will exit the loop and continue to the next part of the program. If input not equal to answer the loop will continue until input is equal to answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the line "`input = reader.nextInt();`" where you get the input from the user? If so, then that line also needs to be inside the while loop so you can get another guess from the user. But don't use the definition "int" the second time, or you will get an "already defined" error.

Also, isn't the "`if(input == answer) {`" test unnecessary, since if the answer were not correct you'd still be in the while loop?

Comment: So initialize input outside the loop, then redefine it every pass of the while loop? I see. Also yes the if statement shouldn't even be required, feels very redundant now that you mention. Thank you!

Comment: Not redefine it, just reference it inside the loop. As I said, if you try to redefine a variable you will get an error.

Comment: Not redefine it, just reference it inside the loop. As I said, if you try to redefine a variable you will get an error. I think you could even define "input" outside the loop, and then do the while loop like this: while( answer != input = reader.nextInt() ){}.  I believe that should execute the nextInt() function first, assign the result to "input", and then perform the comparison with "answer", all in one statement.